# How do I update a table from a SELECT statement in SSMS 2012?

Tags: t-sql, ssms-2012

I have a table that I would like to update based on the results of a query.  The table that I want updated is called dbo.CSL.  The field I want to update is called dbo.CSL.PartType.  How can I update this field based on the results of this query?

```
SELECT
    b.Part,
    b.PartCreated,
    b.LastSalesDate,
    CASE WHEN b.LastSalesDate < (getdate()-365) OR b.LastSalesDate IS NULL AND b.PartCreated <= '2013-12-31' THEN 'C'
        WHEN b.LastSalesDate < (getdate()-365) OR b.LastSalesDate IS NULL AND b.PartCreated >= '2014-01-01' THEN 'N'
    ELSE 'D'
    END AS PartType
FROM
(SELECT
    a.Part,
    a.PartCreated,
    MAX(s.SBINDT) AS LastSalesDate
FROM
    dbo.SalesData s
    RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT
    c.Part,
    c.PartCreated
FROM
    dbo.NewCSL c
) AS a
ON a.Part = s.SBITEM AND s.SBTYPE = 'O'
GROUP BY
    a.Part,
    a.PartCreated
) AS b
ORDER BY
    LastSalesDate
```

Comment: First of all, remove the `order by`

Then say what is the new value for **PartType**

Comment: Have you tried using CTE?

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
UPDATE dbo.CSL 
SET dbo.CSL.PartType = (SELECT TOP 1 
                        FROM MyTable 
                        WHERE TableX = ConditionX) 
WHERE Field1 = Condition1
```

You have to change your statement to return only one row and one column, and then set it to the update statement, or instead concatenate the info.

Cheers.

Comment: That's not at all what I am trying to do.  Each table contains the same field, Part.  I want to link on the Part field and update the PartType field from the query results.